# How to run Tests on Multiple versions of Maven with takari?

Tags: maven, testing, build

I am trying to run maven build on machine for facebook-swift.  Some tests have `@MavenVersions({"3.2.3", "3.2.5", "3.3.1"})` and running the mvn build fails with 
`The plugin io.takari.maven.plugins:takari-lifecycle-plugin:1.11.3 requires Maven version [3.2.1,) -> [Help 1]`
[UPDATE]
After running with required version maven now the error is

```
java.lang.Exception: Could not resolve maven version 3.3.1
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenJUnitTestRunner$1.error(MavenJUnitTestRunner.java:129)
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.resolve(MavenVersionResolver.java:58)
    ...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not download maven version 3.3.1 from any configured repository
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.createMavenInstallation(MavenVersionResolver.java:169)
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.resolve(MavenVersionResolver.java:56)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: HTTP/401 Unauthorized
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.openStream(MavenVersionResolver.java:198)
    at io.takari.maven.testing.executor.junit.MavenVersionResolver.createMavenInstallation(MavenVersionResolver.java:152)
    ... 25 more
```

repeated for each version of maven specified in @MavenVersions

I read the [takari docs](http://takari.io/book/70-testing.html#writing-a-test) but still at a loss why takari can't download or how to set it up so it is able download

[/UPDATE]

Here is the file in question https://github.com/facebook/swift/blob/master/swift-maven-plugin/src/test/java/com/facebook/mojo/SwiftIntegrationTest.java

My question is, How can I run the tests against multiple versions of Maven?

Thanks

Comment: You have to run your build with Maven 3.2.1 at minimum...which the error message says...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks, I was thinking that  message is connected to MavenVersions annotation.

Comment: No it is related to takari-lifecycle-plugin...